# Multer image updating using Node.js

Tags: node.js, multer

This is my Node Controller.Please take a look my last function (productUpdate).Other product details are updating. But image not updating.I think saving error. Please help me solve this problem.

```
const updateProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const productId = req.params.id;
    const { updatedData } = req.body;
    const image = req.file;

  
    // Find the product by ID and update the fields
    const updatedProduct = await Products.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, updatedData,image, { new: true });

    if (!updatedProduct) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "Product not found" });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Product updated successfully", updatedProduct });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```